# How can you make a hyperlink do an action in PHP?

Tags: php, hyperlink

what I am trying to do is make a 'logout' hyperlink on my website change a session variable to make the user appear logged out, but I'm having difficulty doing so. Is this possible?

I understand how to change the variable and that, but I am struggling to get this to happen within a hyper link.

(Keep in mind this is a simple student demonstration I am using to basically log a user in from an MySQL database to view the same stuff as other current users.)

Answer (score 3):

`<a href="logout.php">logout</a>` on `logout.php` simply `unset` the `session` and redirect home page

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is Server Side you have to have the link call to the server to perform an action. As Praveen showed, you need to navigate to a new PHP page.

You could also have JavaScript perform an AJAX request but it won't do much to logout because most of the content on the page will likely need to be updated since you are no longer logged in.

In the logout.php page, you can then redirect away from it using

```
header('Location: login.php');
die();
```

So after the user goes to logout.php (unsets Cookies and Sessions), they get redirected to login.php automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Within a hyperlink should mean, a hyperlink leading to the same page or what?

page.php:

```
<a href="page.php?logout=1">logout</a>
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['session']);
}
```

But I don't see any logic in doing it at all

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href='index.php?logout'>Logout</a>"
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
}
```